# Finding counts of each occurrence in R

Tags: r, dataframe, unique

I am trying to find the number of occurrences of each string within a certain row of a data frame in R. I assume I would use the unique() function.
For example, If I wanted a count of how many times **each** type of dog showed up within a data frame, how would I go about this?
Thanks!

Comment: I didn't follow. Would you like all occurrences in a table or by row? If it has some specific column to match you may use grep or even `string` package

Comment: The sum of each unique occurrence. I.e. how many times "Golden Retriever", "Labrador", and "Chow Chow" each show up

Comment: Have you tried `table(df$columnname)`? Anything further and you will need to provide usable sample data, perhaps the output from `dput(head(x))`.

Comment: @RyanRiley could you give us an example of your table? Because is quiet easy if it is just within one column, but if it is for any column might be quiet different. Depends of your table.

Answer (score 1):

It would be best if you gave a reproducible example. but...

```
sum(df[row_num, ] %in% c("Golden Retriever"))
```

would give the number of occurrences of "Golden Retreiver" in the first row. Iterating using a for loop would work for whole data frame.

Using the dplyr package you can do a rowwise operation to to populate a new column with the count. eg.

```
df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(gold_count = sum(c(col_name1, col_name2, ...,) %in% "Golden Retriever"))
```

you can do this for all the other as well

Comment: `df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(gold_count = sum(colnames(.) %in% "Golden Retriever"))` ??